# Convert 4D array of floats from txt (string) file to numpy array of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a txt (string) file looking like:

```
[[[[0.17262284, 0.95086717, 0.01172171, 0.79262904],
     [0.52454078, 0.16740103, 0.32694925, 0.78921072],
     [0.77886716, 0.35550488, 0.89272706, 0.36761104]],
    [[0.14336841, 0.94488079, 0.83388505, 0.02065268],
     [0.31804594, 0.22056339, 0.84088501, 0.94994676],
     [0.57845057, 0.12645735, 0.12628646, 0.05526736]]]]
```

The shape is (1,2,3,4).
How can I easily convert it to a `NumPy` array that considers the data type and the shape (that may be deduced from the parenthesis)?
Let's say I have the shape in the txt file, will it make it easier?
I have tried using `np.loadtxt`, seems that it doesn't handle this 4d shape, it loads as a 1D array.
I can parse the shape myself and then convert all members to floats but I believe there is np function that already does that. The file is not created by me - I would just pkl the array.

Comment: How did you create the file? What exactly happened when you "tried using np.loadtxt"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text string containing the array can be evaluated ('read') using the `ast.literal_eval()` function, then wrapped in a numpy array constructor, as:

```
import ast
import numpy as np


# Option 1: From a text string.
a = np.array(ast.literal_eval(txt))

# Option 2: Directly from text file.
a = np.array(ast.literal_eval(open('np_array.txt').read()))

a.shape
>>> (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Setup:

```
txt = """[[[[0.17262284, 0.95086717, 0.01172171, 0.79262904],
[0.52454078, 0.16740103, 0.32694925, 0.78921072],
[0.77886716, 0.35550488, 0.89272706, 0.36761104]],
[[0.14336841, 0.94488079, 0.83388505, 0.02065268],
[0.31804594, 0.22056339, 0.84088501, 0.94994676],
[0.57845057, 0.12645735, 0.12628646, 0.05526736]]]]"""
```

Comment: Huh.  A documented, built-in, safe version of `eval`.  Haven't seen that before.

Comment: @DanielF - Yes, a very useful / safe tool.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

This array encoding matches the encoding scheme of json, so you can use that to load it:

```
import json
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(json.load(open("array.txt", "r")))
```

Or if the data is a string, use:

```
arr = np.array(json.loads(array_as_string))
```