# convert string to numpy array python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a string like that:

```
'[[-1. ]
 [ 4.5]
 [ 0. ]]

[[ 8.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 6.]]

[[ 0.        ]
 [ 4.        ]
 [ 0.66666667]]'
```

and I want to convert into a NumPy array like this

```
array([[[-1.        ],
        [ 4.5       ],
        [ 0.        ]],

       [[ 8.        ],
        [ 0.        ],
        [ 6.        ]],

       [[ 0.        ],
        [ 4.        ],
        [ 0.66666667]]])
```

i try this code but didn't gat my answer

```
np.array(list(string.replace(']','],')))
```

Comment: For your firsts steps I will do something like: `# Remove all white spaces
while string.find(" ") != -1:
    string = string.replace(" ", "")

# Add comma between brackets
string = string.replace("][", "],[")` Then you will need to convert it into a list object where each element is a string you can convert into an int.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert 4D array of floats from txt (string) file to numpy array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986545/convert-4d-array-of-floats-from-txt-string-file-to-numpy-array-of-floats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the size before hand then

```
np.fromstring(
    s.replace('[', '').replace(']','').replace('\n', ''), 
                dtype=float, sep=' ').reshape(3,3)
```

Testcase:

```
s = '''[[-1. ]
 [ 4.5]
 [ 0. ]]

[[ 8.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 6.]]

[[ 0.        ]
 [ 4.        ]
 [ 0.66666667]]'''

np.fromstring(
    s.replace('[', '').replace(']','').replace('\n', ''), 
                dtype=float, sep=' ').reshape(3,3)
```

Output:

```
array([[-1.        ,  4.5       ,  0.        ],
       [ 8.        ,  0.        ,  6.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  4.        ,  0.66666667]])
```